# Merging the common substring in three string of acolumn in oracle

Tags: java, string, oracle, group-by

I have three column as following -

```
Dated                    status                count 
01-02-13              1A + 2B + 73PLO           76
01-02-13              29A + 17ACB               46
01-02-13              9PLO + 11B + 5TY          25
02-02-13              18FGH + 23B + 4ACB        45
02-02-13              8ACB + 12A + 2FGH         22
02-02-13              6A + 2B + 42ACB           50
03-02-13              .....                     ...
............
```

So, My final result should add the three strings('status') for a particular 'dated' but keeping in mind the common sub-strings of the three strings for a particular date as follows -

```
dated                     status                            count
01-02-13         30A + 13B + 82PLO + 17ACB + 5TY             147
02-02-13         20FGH + 25B + 73PLO + 54ACB + 18A           117
03-02-13              ......(and similarly)                  ....
```

Here, I have actually created a group by expression on 'dated' by adding the count and merging the 'status', but actually I am unable to reach this....
Some help is needed.

Comment: Post your code, please.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fff5a/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Data ( Dated, status, "count" ) AS
          SELECT TO_DATE( '01-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '1A + 2B + 73PLO', 76 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '01-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '29A + 17ACB', 46 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '01-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '0A + 1ACB', 46 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '01-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '9PLO + 11B + 5TY', 25 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '02-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '18FGH + 23B + 4ACB', 45 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '02-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '8ACB + 12A + 2FGH', 22 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT TO_DATE( '02-02-13', 'DD-MM-YY' ), '6A + 2B + 42ACB', 50 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

A SQL solution which is valid for Oracle 11g R1 (although if you replace `REGEXP_COUNT` with `LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(status,'\d+[A-Z]+( \+ |$)', 'X'))` then you should be able to use it in, I think, Oracle 9i):

```
WITH counts AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SUM( "count" ) AS total_count
  FROM Data
  GROUP BY Dated
),
split_statuses AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         Dated,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) ) AS num_status,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2) AS val_status
  FROM   Data
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)')
),
summed_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SUM( num_status ) || val_status AS totaled_status,
         val_status
  FROM   split_statuses
  GROUP BY Dated, val_status
),
indexed_summed_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         totaled_status,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Dated ORDER BY val_status ) AS idx
  FROM   summed_statuses
),
grouped_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( totaled_status, ' + ' ) AS status,
         idx
  FROM   indexed_summed_statuses
  START WITH idx = 1
  CONNECT BY PRIOR idx + 1 = idx AND prior Dated = Dated
),
max_grouped_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SUBSTR( MAX( status ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY idx ), 4 ) AS status
  FROM   grouped_statuses
  GROUP BY Dated
)
SELECT m.Dated,
       status,
       total_count
FROM   max_grouped_statuses m
       INNER JOIN
       counts c
       ON ( m.Dated = c.Dated )
ORDER BY Dated
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fff5a/5/0)**:

```
|                           DATED |                          STATUS | TOTAL_COUNT |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|-------------|
| February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 30A + 18ACB + 13B + 82PLO + 5TY |         193 |
| February, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       18A + 54ACB + 25B + 20FGH |         117 |
```

**Query 2**:

A simpler solution available with Oracle 11g R2:

```
WITH counts AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SUM( "count" ) AS total_count
  FROM Data
  GROUP BY Dated
),
split_statuses AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         Dated,
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 1) ) AS num_status,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)', 1, LEVEL, NULL, 2) AS val_status
  FROM   Data
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(status, '(\d+)([A-Z]+)')
),
summed_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         SUM( num_status ) || val_status AS totaled_status,
         val_status
  FROM   split_statuses
  GROUP BY Dated, val_status
),
grouped_statuses AS (
  SELECT Dated,
         LISTAGG( totaled_status, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val_status) AS status
  FROM   summed_statuses
  GROUP BY Dated
)
SELECT g.Dated,
       status,
       total_count
FROM   grouped_statuses g
       INNER JOIN
       counts c
       ON ( g.Dated = c.Dated )
ORDER BY Dated
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/fff5a/5/1)**:

```
|                           DATED |                          STATUS | TOTAL_COUNT |
|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|-------------|
| February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | 30A + 18ACB + 13B + 82PLO + 5TY |         193 |
| February, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 |       18A + 54ACB + 25B + 20FGH |         117 |
```

Comment: This wont return correct sum if the "count" column has repeated values for a same date.

Comment: Good catch, thanks - its now fixed it to show the correct sum for the `count` column on duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested thoroughly,but i think this is what is required by you,I have not considered all the test cases ,may be the total count differ in some situation,but the status grouping is correct.

```
 SELECT dated
      ,LISTAGG(num||val, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val) status
     ,MAX(cnt) "count"
 FROM
  --middle section start
  (
    SELECT dated
          ,SUM(regexp_substr(sub_status,'[0-9]+')) num
         ,regexp_substr(sub_status,'[A-Z]+')val,MAX(cnt) cnt
     FROM
        --inner section start
        (
         SELECT DISTINCT dated
                        ,TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '[^+]+', 1, LEVEL)) sub_status
                        ,SUM(DISTINCT "count") OVER(PARTITION BY dated) cnt
         FROM DATA
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(status, '[^+]+')) + 1
         )
         --inner section end 
   GROUP BY dated
           ,regexp_substr(sub_status,'[A-Z]+')
   )
   --middle section end
 GROUP BY dated;
```

1. inner section :first i tried to separate all the different values in rows that are seperated by `+`
2. And then i further seperate the value ,removing the numerical part and the alphabetic part.
3. Middle section :I tried doing the sum of numerical part based on grouping dated column and the alphabetic part.
4. outer section :I combine the result of middle section based on dated column,separated by `+`

*Note*I have not tested this ,but this should be the approach to solve this ,not considered count having same value in the same group

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dc4ec/42)